# GPU temperature monitor that stays on top while playing

Tags: software-rec, gpu

Is there a GPU temperature monitor that will stay on top while playing a game?

- [realtemp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) doesn't detect my GPU.
- [hwmonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) does, but it doesn't stay on top.

What are some other alternatives?

I have an ATI Radeon 5770.

Comment: What is your OS? My answer assumes windows XP, Vista, or 7.

Answer (score 1):

try [GameOverlay](http://www.fileguru.com/Game-Overlay/info):

> Run a utility in the background checking temperatures, download speeds, etc, then overlay it!Game Overlay works with Direct3D, OpenGL, and DirectDraw games and applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Desk Pins](http://www.snapfiles.com/opinions/DeskPins/DeskPins.html) program with hwmonitor. It should be able to force the window to stay on top.

Comment: i doubt that it will stay atop a fullscreen window. which is the tricky part here...

Comment: I would try it. It did get great reviews...

Comment: yah, but the chair i am sitting on got great reviews as well and somehow it can't make a pizza...

Comment: Don't see how it can hurt to try...

Comment: it wont hurt. i just expressed my feelings towards the outcome. 'ontop' only is something usefull when you have layered windows. with games you don't have that, you have one big window, fullscreen. and fullscreen means ontop-of-all-other-apps, no matter how layered they are.

Answer (score 0):

try [PlayXPert](http://www.playxpert.com/):

> The Diagnostics Widget allows you to monitor and adjust system performance in-game within a killer user interface.  This widget brings you real-time data on utilization and performance of your CPU, memory, network bandwidth, and processes.  You can even kill runaway processes right within the game if it’s impacting your ability to frag your way to victory.

Comment: Why two different answers as opposed to an edit?

Comment: because of 2 different products. the one looks better than the other, but OP decides on this.